# Accessing the code section of a C++ program

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management, elf

Based upon my understanding, a C/C++ program looks something like this in the memory:

[image: Memory Layout of C programs. Source : Internet]

I wanted to know the following :

1. Can I access the "text section" of the running program? By accessing I mean printing
   the start and end addresses and examining the contents.
2. Can I relocate the "text section" to some other address in the memory at runtime?

Thanks,

Comment: If you want a specific function you can just directly access its pointer for reading and copying to another space. Mind you that there's a huge performance impact for handling code as data.

Comment: **Why** exactly do you ask? **What do you want to do**, really?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Actually, I want to compute the impact of accessing code from a node other than the one running the current program on a NUMA machine. I know there are other alternatives, but was curious if one can access the text section and modify it to point to some other address at runtime.

Comment: Well, processors have caches, so the impact (for hot code used often) should not be significant. And even without NUMA, cache misses have a huge cost (that matters mostly for *cold* code used rarely). And NUMA systems have a complex MMU (code is in virtual memory!). So hot code is always "on the current node". Don't care that much about code, care about data!

Answer (score 9):

It is operating system specific; I am answering for Linux only.

First your figure is grossly incorrect in practice, since most programs are dynamically linked to several shared object libraries (including `libc6.so`...). See also [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). There is no *single* `text` section (but many "text" like segments). Read about the [pmap](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/pmap/) and [objdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) commands.

Then, you can understand the address space of a process of pid 1234 with `cat /proc/1234/maps` ; read more about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)... From inside the program, read `/proc/self/maps`; for instance try `cat /proc/$$/maps` in a shell to show the address space of the shell process, and `cat /proc/self/maps` for the address space of the process running that `cat` command. See also [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

You cannot really "relocate" (you actually mean "move") the text section. Some addresses are built inside the code. However, read about the [-fPIE option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) of `gcc` (for *position independent executable* ....).

Of course, you can access the symbols of a program (from inside) if you link it with the [-rdynamic](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) flag and if you use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (and `dlsym` and even perhaps `dladdr`....) with a `NULL` first `filename` argument.

See also wikipages about [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR), [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_independent_code), [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29), [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), [JIT compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and the [x86-64 ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) and the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book.